# How to start a custom service

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm very new to Linux and the solution might be easy so excuse me for that.

I'm trying to run an application called EnCase Remote Recovery, which basically takes a remote image of a system. In order to that, a "servlet" must be deployed on the remote machine. I don't care if the servlet started automatically or manually.

Here is what the guide says: (P.S: the servlet name is `enlinuxpc`)

- Method 1: To start it manually:

  - 1.a: Copy the servlet to the machine (Done that).
  - 1.b Insert the following before the STARTX command:LOAD

I have no idea what that means and as far as I know STARTX is something for GUI.
I tried executing this: `STARTX LOAD enlinuxpc` and what I get is this:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: No absolute path found for shell: LOAD
xinit: connection to x server lost
```

- Method 2: Starting it using xinetd

  - 2.a: Create a configuration file named enlinuxpc in the /etc/xinetd.d directory.
  - 2.b: Using a text editor such as vi, insert the following text into the file, then save and close it.

    service enlinuxpc

    {
     socket_type = stream
     protocol = tcp
     port = 4445
     type = UNLISTED
     wait = yes
     user = root
     server = /usr/local/encase/enlinuxpc
     server_args = -i -p /usr/local/encase
     }
  - 2.c: Restart the `xinetd` service.

I've done all these steps, however the servlet still not running.

1. So how can I start it manually?
2. Is there something missing for method 2?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If type is stream, wait should always be no.

http://linux.die.net/man/5/xinetd.conf

under "SENSOR", last sentence.

Comment: `wait` just determines how to handle subsequent connections - `no` mean xinetd will spawn new threads of the server for each new connection, while `yes` means xinetd will stop listening on that port and all future connections are expected to be handled by the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to simply run the servlet from the command shell as a daemon using;

./enlinux64 -d

Add -p to specify a port other than the default.